# sparse table vs separate tables

Tags: c++, database-design, sqlite

I have a `c++` base class `A` and several derived subclasses `B1, B2, B3, ...`. I have an sqlite3 database file with the info to construct instances of these subclasses. Suppose `A` has some members like

```
int number;
std::string label;
```

`B1` adds a member

```
std::string uuid;
```

and `B2` adds a member

```
std::string url;
```

I am inclined to have only one table in the sqlite database for all `A` classes with columns like `(subclass int, number int, label text, uuid text, url text)` where the first column says which is the class I am storing and letting `uuid` be null for all `B2` classes for example.

Another approach would be to have a table for each subclass.

If the number of members in some subclass, say `B3` is large (still not that much, of the order of 15 columns) that would mean that for each class that is not of type `B3` the corresponding row in the first approach will have plenty of `NULL` columns. However I gather that in `SQLite` `NULL` columns do not take much overhead on disk, so is the first approach the right one or is it bad practice?

Comment: Your approaches resemble two techniques described under these two tags:  [tag:single-table-inheritance] and [tag:class-table-inheritance]

Comment: @RustyX In the [SQLite on-disk record format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format), a NULL value occupies one byte for the type code.